# Javascript - Different conditions for each element in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am building a simple quiz where 10 questions are asked with `radio` inputs. The maximum mark you can get is 10. Each incorrect answer is -0.5p and you have the option of not answering by choosing "I don't want to answer this question".

I'm struggling to calculate the total mark because there are lots of `if` for each correct/incorrect/NA answer, so what I thought was to create an array: `var CorrectAnswers=["Question 1","Question 2",...]` and apply conditions like for example: `if("CorrectAnswers[0]==true])mark=mark+1;`.

But the list of `if` would be too long.
Is there any way to simplify this and tell the program to check which answers where correct/incorrect/NA and add 1/-0.5/0 to the mark?

It is not in english but hope you can understand it.

```js
//P1-2, P2-2, P3-3, P4-2, P5-4, P6-3, P7-4, P8-3, P9-2, P10-2
function calcul(){
  //Respostes correctes
  var p1c=document.getElementById("p1r2").checked;
  var p2c=document.getElementById("p2r2").checked;
  var p3c=document.getElementById("p3r3").checked;
  var p4c=document.getElementById("p4r2").checked;
  var p5c=document.getElementById("p5r4").checked;
  var p6c=document.getElementById("p6r3").checked;
  var p7c=document.getElementById("p7r4").checked;
  var p8c=document.getElementById("p8r3").checked;
  var p9c=document.getElementById("p9r2").checked;
  var p10c=document.getElementById("p10r2").checked;
  var RespostesCorrectes=[p1c,p2c,p3c,p4c,p5c,p6c,p7c,p8c,p9c,p10c];
  //No contestades
  var p1n=document.getElementById("p1r0").checked;
  var p2n=document.getElementById("p2r0").checked;
  var p3n=document.getElementById("p3r0").checked;
  var p4n=document.getElementById("p4r0").checked;
  var p5n=document.getElementById("p5r0").checked;
  var p6n=document.getElementById("p6r0").checked;
  var p7n=document.getElementById("p7r0").checked;
  var p8n=document.getElementById("p8r0").checked;
  var p9n=document.getElementById("p9r0").checked;
  var p10n=document.getElementById("p10r0").checked;
  var RespostesNA=[p1n,p2n,p3n,p4n,p5n,p6n,p7n,p8n,p9n,p10n];
  //Calcular nota i pregs correctes/incorrectes
  nota=0;
  if(p1c==true)nota=nota+1;
  if(p2c==true)nota=nota+1;
  if(p3c==true)nota=nota+1;
  if(p4c==true)nota=nota+1;
  if(p5c==true)nota=nota+1;
  if(p6c==true)nota=nota+1;
  if(p7c==true)nota=nota+1;
  if(p8c==true)nota=nota+1;
  if(p9c==true)nota=nota+1;
  if(p10c==true)nota=nota+1;
}
```

```css
.codiPrograma{
  font-family:"Courier", Courier, sans-serif;
  font-size: 17px;
}
.codi{
  font-family:"Courier", Courier, sans-serif;
  font-size: 15px;
}
.boto{
  width:150px;
  height:30px;
  font-size:15px;
  margin:0 auto;
  display: block;
}
#test{
  /*display:none;*/
  width:1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
#resultats{
  width: 250px;
  height:400px;
  border: 5px solid black;
  padding: 25px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top:30px;
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<div id="test">
<fieldset class="pregunta">
<legend>Pregunta 1</legend>
 <h3>Quin és el valor de l'expressió següent? <br>
   <span class="codiPrograma"><p> &quot;23&quot;+12</p></span>
 </h3>
 <div class="respostes">
 <input type="radio" name="pregunta1" id="p1r1">
 <label class="codi" for="p1r1">35</label><br>
 <input type="radio" name="pregunta1" id="p1r2">
 <label class="codi" for="p1r2">&quot;2312&quot;</label><br>
 <input type="radio" name="pregunta1" id="p1r3">
 <label class="codi" for="p1r3">&quot;35&quot;</label><br>
 <input type="radio" name="pregunta1" id="p1r4">
 <label for="p1r4">No es pot avaluar perquè és sintàcticament incorrecte.</label><br>
 <input type="radio" name="pregunta1" id="p1r0">
 <label for="p1r0">No contesto</label><br>
 </div>
</fieldset>
<fieldset class="pregunta">
<legend>Pregunta 2</legend>
 <h3>Quin és el valor de l'expressió següent? <br>
   <span class="codiPrograma"><p>"23"&gt;12 &amp;&amp; !(parseInt("12px")&lt;13)</p></span>
 </h3>
 <div class="respostes">
 <input type="radio" name="pregunta2" id="p2r1">
 <label class="codi" for="p2r1">true</label><br>
 <input type="radio" name="pregunta2" id="p2r2">
 <label class="codi" for="p2r2">false</label><br>
 <input type="radio" name="pregunta2" id="p2r3">
 <label class="codi" for="p2r3">undefined</label><br>
 <input type="radio" name="pregunta2" id="p2r4">
 <label for="p2r4">No es pot avaluar perquè és sintàcticament incorrecte.</label><br>
 <input type="radio" name="pregunta2" id="p2r0">
 <label for="p2r0">No contesto</label><br>
 </div>
</fieldset>
<fieldset class="pregunta">
<legend>Pregunta 3</legend>
 <h3>Quina és la condició per saber que el valor de la variable x és un número parell i no múltiple de 3?</h3>
 <div class="respostes">
 <input type="radio" name="pregunta3" id="p3r1">
 <label class="codi" for="p3r1">x%2==0 && !x%3==0</label><br>
 <input type="radio" name="pregunta3" id="p3r2">
 <label class="codi" for="p3r2">x/2=0 && !(x/3=0)</label><br>
 <input type="radio" name="pregunta3" id="p3r3">
 <label class="codi" for="p3r3">x%2==0 && !(x%3==0)</label><br>
 <input type="radio" name="pregunta3" id="p3r4">
 <label class="codi" for="p3r4">x%2=0 && !(x%3=0)</label><br>
 <input type="radio" name="pregunta3" id="p3r0">
 <label for="p3r0">No contesto</label><br>
 </div>
</fieldset>
<fieldset class="pregunta">
<legend>Pregunta 4</legend>
 <h3>Quina és la instrucció adequada per llegir el valor entrat per l'usuari a través del següent element HTML? <br>
 <span class="codiPrograma"><p>&lt;input type="text" id="a"&gt;</p></span>
 </h3>
 <div class="respostes">
 <input type="radio" name="pregunta4" id="p4r1">
 <label class="codi" for="p4r1">var x = document.getElementById('a').value;</label><br>
 <input type="radio" name="pregunta4" id="p4r2">
 <label class="codi" for="p4r2">var a = document.getElementById("a").value;</label><br>
 <input type="radio" name="pregunta4" id="p4r3">
 <label class="codi" for="p4r3">var a = document.getElementById("a").value();</label><br>
 <input type="radio" name="pregunta4" id="p4r4">
 <label for="p4r4">No es pot llegir perquè falta l'atribut size en l'element HTML</label><br>
 <input type="radio" name="pregunta4" id="p4r0">
 <label for="p4r0">No contesto</label><br>
 </div>
</fieldset>
<fieldset class="pregunta">
<legend>Pregunta 5</legend>
 <h3>Quin és el resultat d'executar la següent funció? <br>
   <span class="codiPrograma"><p>function pregunta5(){</br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;const A=5, B=10;</br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;return B%2 - A*B/2;<br>}</p></span>
 </h3>
 <div class="respostes">
 <input type="radio" name="pregunta5" id="p5r1">
 <label class="codi" for="p5r1">25</label><br>
 <input type="radio" name="pregunta5" id="p5r2">
 <label class="codi" for="p5r2">-20</label><br>
 <input type="radio" name="pregunta5" id="p5r3">
 <label for="p5r3">No es pot executar perquè té errors sintàctics</label><br>
 <input type="radio" name="pregunta5" id="p5r4">
 <label class="codi" for="p5r4">-25</label><br>
 <input type="radio" name="pregunta5" id="p5r0">
 <label for="p5r0">No contesto</label><br>
 </div>
</fieldset>
<fieldset class="pregunta">
<legend>Pregunta 6</legend>
 <h3>Quin és el resultat d'executar la funció programa()?<br>
   <span class="codiPrograma"><p>function programa(){<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;var x=2, y=5;<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;y=pregunta6(x,y);<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;alert("El resultat és " + x);<br>}<br>function pregunta6(x,y){<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;x=x+y;<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;return x;<br>}</p></span>
 </h3>
 <div class="respostes">
 <input type="radio" name="pregunta6" id="p6r1">
 <label class="codi" for="p6r1">El resultat és 5</label><br>
 <input type="radio" name="pregunta6" id="p6r2">
 <label class="codi" for="p6r2">El resultat és 7</label><br>
 <input type="radio" name="pregunta6" id="p6r3">
 <label class="codi" for="p6r3">El resultat és 2</label><br>
 <input type="radio" name="pregunta6" id="p6r4">
 <label class="codi" for="p6r4">El resultat és 6</label><br>
 <input type="radio" name="pregunta6" id="p6r0">
 <label for="p6r0">No contesto</label><br>
 </div>
</fieldset>
<fieldset class="pregunta">
<legend>Pregunta 7</legend>
 <h3>Quina d'aquestes funcions NO calcula correctament la suma de tots els nombres imparells que hi ha entre 5 i 186, ambdós inclosos? <br>
 <span class="codiPrograma"> <br>function funcioA() {<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;var resultat=0;<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;var i;<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;for (i=186; i>5; i--)<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;if(i%2==1) resultat=resultat+i;<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;return resultat;<br>}<br>function funcioB(){<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;var resultat=0;<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;var i;<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;for(i=5; i&lt;=186; i++)<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;if(i%2==1) resultat=resultat+i;<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;return resultat;<br>}<br>function funcioC(){<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;var resultat=0;<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;var i;<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;for(i=5; i&lt;=186; i=i+2)<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;resultat=resultat+i;<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;return resultat;<br>}<br>function funcioD(){<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;var resultat=0;<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;var i;<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;for(i=5; i&lt;=186; i++)<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;if(i%2=1) resultat=resultat+i;<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;return resultat;<br>}</span>
 </h3>
 <div class="respostes">
 <input type="radio" name="pregunta7" id="p7r1">
 <label class="codi" for="p7r1">funcioA</label><br>
 <input type="radio" name="pregunta7" id="p7r2">
 <label class="codi" for="p7r2">funcioB</label><br>
 <input type="radio" name="pregunta7" id="p7r3">
 <label class="codi" for="p7r3">funcioC</label><br>
 <input type="radio" name="pregunta7" id="p7r4">
 <label class="codi" for="p7r4">funcioD</label><br>
 <input type="radio" name="pregunta7" id="p7r0">
 <label for="p7r0">No contesto</label><br>
 </div>
</fieldset>
<fieldset class="pregunta">
<legend>Pregunta 8</legend>
 <h3>Donat l'objecte <span class="codiPrograma">var rectangle={posicio: {x:"3", y:"5"}, amplada:"10", alçada:"20"}</span> quina expressió calcula correctament l'àrea del mateix?
 </h3>
 <div class="respostes">
 <input type="radio" name="pregunta8" id="p8r1">
 <label class="codi" for="p8r1">amplada*alçada</label><br>
 <input type="radio" name="pregunta8" id="p8r2">
 <label class="codi" for="p8r2">amplada.rectangle*alçada.rectangle</label><br>
 <input type="radio" name="pregunta8" id="p8r3">
 <label class="codi" for="p8r3">rectangle.amplada*rectangle.alçada</label><br>
 <input type="radio" name="pregunta8" id="p8r4">
 <label class="codi" for="p8r4">parseInt("rectangle.amplada")*parseInt("rectangle.alçada")</label><br>
 <input type="radio" name="pregunta8" id="p8r0">
 <label for="p8r0">No contesto</label><br>
 </div>
</fieldset>
<fieldset class="pregunta">
<legend>Pregunta 9</legend>
 <h3>Amb el mateix rectangle de la pregunta anterior, quina instrucció el mouria a la nova posició<span class="codiPrograma"> x="7"</span> i <span class="codiPrograma">y="9"</span>?
 </h3>
 <div class="respostes">
 <input type="radio" name="pregunta9" id="p9r1">
 <label class="codi" for="p9r1">rectangle.posiciox="7"; rectangle.posicioy="9";</label><br>
 <input type="radio" name="pregunta9" id="p9r2">
 <label class="codi" for="p9r2">rectangle.posicio.y="9"; rectangle.posicio.x="7";</label><br>
 <input type="radio" name="pregunta9" id="p9r3">
 <label class="codi" for="p9r3">posicio.x="7"; posicio.y="9";</label><br>
 <input type="radio" name="pregunta9" id="p9r4">
 <label class="codi" for="p9r4">posicio.x="7" && posicio.y="9";</label><br>
 <input type="radio" name="pregunta9" id="p9r0">
 <label for="p9r0">No contesto</label><br>
 </div>
</fieldset>
<fieldset class="pregunta">
<legend>Pregunta 10</legend>
 <h3>Quina cadena de caràcters avalua la següent expressió? <br>
 <span class="codiPrograma">"Hola. ".charAt(2)+"Que tal?".toLowerCase()</span>
 </h3>
 <div class="respostes">
 <input type="radio" name="pregunta10" id="p10r1">
 <label class="codi" for="p10r1">"Hola. Que tal?"</label><br>
 <input type="radio" name="pregunta10" id="p10r2">
 <label class="codi" for="p10r2">"lque tal="</label><br>
 <input type="radio" name="pregunta10" id="p10r3">
 <label class="codi" for="p10r3">"oque tal??"</label><br>
 <input type="radio" name="pregunta10" id="p10r4">
 <label class="codi" for="p10r4">"hola. que tal?"</label><br>
 <input type="radio" name="pregunta10" id="p10r0">
 <label for="p10r0">No contesto</label><br>
 </div>
</fieldset>
<br>
<button id="boto" class="boto" type="button" onClick="calcul()">Calcular Nota</button>
</div>
```

Comment: [Without a Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example, it is hard to know what is wrong](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nomcve/)

Comment: Added the snippet.

Comment: You'll probably want some sort of [`for`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) [loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration). If your code is working as is and you're looking at tips for improving readability, you might consider posting it over at [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @p.s.w.g - I'm stuck here, not looking for an improved readability. I do not think all those `if` will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I hinted at in my comment, you can use a [`for`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) loop. You already have the correct answers and 'N/A' answers in arrays so you can easily loop over them. The pseudo code would be something like:

```
score <- 0
for each question
   if correct answer selected then
       score <- score + 1
   else if n/a answer not selected then
       score <- score - 0.5
   end
next question
```

Translating this to javascript, you'd have something like this:

```
var nota = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < RespostesCorrectes.length; i++) {
  if (RespostesCorrectes[i]) {
    nota += 1;
  } else if (!RespostesNA[i]) {
    nota -= 0.5;
  }
}
```

Finally, you need to display the result score to the user. For this simple example, `alert` will be good enough.

```js
//P1-2, P2-2, P3-3, P4-2, P5-4, P6-3, P7-4, P8-3, P9-2, P10-2
function calcul(){
  //Respostes correctes
  var p1c=document.getElementById("p1r2").checked;
  var p2c=document.getElementById("p2r2").checked;
  var p3c=document.getElementById("p3r3").checked;
  var p4c=document.getElementById("p4r2").checked;
  var p5c=document.getElementById("p5r4").checked;
  var p6c=document.getElementById("p6r3").checked;
  var p7c=document.getElementById("p7r4").checked;
  var p8c=document.getElementById("p8r3").checked;
  var p9c=document.getElementById("p9r2").checked;
  var p10c=document.getElementById("p10r2").checked;
  var RespostesCorrectes=[p1c,p2c,p3c,p4c,p5c,p6c,p7c,p8c,p9c,p10c];
  //No contestades
  var p1n=document.getElementById("p1r0").checked;
  var p2n=document.getElementById("p2r0").checked;
  var p3n=document.getElementById("p3r0").checked;
  var p4n=document.getElementById("p4r0").checked;
  var p5n=document.getElementById("p5r0").checked;
  var p6n=document.getElementById("p6r0").checked;
  var p7n=document.getElementById("p7r0").checked;
  var p8n=document.getElementById("p8r0").checked;
  var p9n=document.getElementById("p9r0").checked;
  var p10n=document.getElementById("p10r0").checked;
  var RespostesNA=[p1n,p2n,p3n,p4n,p5n,p6n,p7n,p8n,p9n,p10n];
  //Calcular nota i pregs correctes/incorrectes
  var nota = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < RespostesCorrectes.length; i++) {
    if (RespostesCorrectes[i]) {
      nota += 1;
    } else if (!RespostesNA[i]) {
      nota -= 0.5;
    }
  }

  alert(nota);
}
```

```css
.codiPrograma{
  font-family:"Courier", Courier, sans-serif;
  font-size: 17px;
}
.codi{
  font-family:"Courier", Courier, sans-serif;
  font-size: 15px;
}
.boto{
  width:150px;
  height:30px;
  font-size:15px;
  margin:0 auto;
  display: block;
}
#test{
  /*display:none;*/
  width:1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
#resultats{
  width: 250px;
  height:400px;
  border: 5px solid black;
  padding: 25px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top:30px;
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<div id="test">
<fieldset class="pregunta">
<legend>Pregunta 1</legend>
 <h3>Quin és el valor de l'expressió següent? <br>
   <span class="codiPrograma"><p> &quot;23&quot;+12</p></span>
 </h3>
 <div class="respostes">
 <input type="radio" name="pregunta1" id="p1r1">
 <label class="codi" for="p1r1">35</label><br>
 <input type="radio" name="pregunta1" id="p1r2">
 <label class="codi" for="p1r2">&quot;2312&quot;</label><br>
 <input type="radio" name="pregunta1" id="p1r3">
 <label class="codi" for="p1r3">&quot;35&quot;</label><br>
 <input type="radio" name="pregunta1" id="p1r4">
 <label for="p1r4">No es pot avaluar perquè és sintàcticament incorrecte.</label><br>
 <input type="radio" name="pregunta1" id="p1r0">
 <label for="p1r0">No contesto</label><br>
 </div>
</fieldset>
<fieldset class="pregunta">
<legend>Pregunta 2</legend>
 <h3>Quin és el valor de l'expressió següent? <br>
   <span class="codiPrograma"><p>"23"&gt;12 &amp;&amp; !(parseInt("12px")&lt;13)</p></span>
 </h3>
 <div class="respostes">
 <input type="radio" name="pregunta2" id="p2r1">
 <label class="codi" for="p2r1">true</label><br>
 <input type="radio" name="pregunta2" id="p2r2">
 <label class="codi" for="p2r2">false</label><br>
 <input type="radio" name="pregunta2" id="p2r3">
 <label class="codi" for="p2r3">undefined</label><br>
 <input type="radio" name="pregunta2" id="p2r4">
 <label for="p2r4">No es pot avaluar perquè és sintàcticament incorrecte.</label><br>
 <input type="radio" name="pregunta2" id="p2r0">
 <label for="p2r0">No contesto</label><br>
 </div>
</fieldset>
<fieldset class="pregunta">
<legend>Pregunta 3</legend>
 <h3>Quina és la condició per saber que el valor de la variable x és un número parell i no múltiple de 3?</h3>
 <div class="respostes">
 <input type="radio" name="pregunta3" id="p3r1">
 <label class="codi" for="p3r1">x%2==0 && !x%3==0</label><br>
 <input type="radio" name="pregunta3" id="p3r2">
 <label class="codi" for="p3r2">x/2=0 && !(x/3=0)</label><br>
 <input type="radio" name="pregunta3" id="p3r3">
 <label class="codi" for="p3r3">x%2==0 && !(x%3==0)</label><br>
 <input type="radio" name="pregunta3" id="p3r4">
 <label class="codi" for="p3r4">x%2=0 && !(x%3=0)</label><br>
 <input type="radio" name="pregunta3" id="p3r0">
 <label for="p3r0">No contesto</label><br>
 </div>
</fieldset>
<fieldset class="pregunta">
<legend>Pregunta 4</legend>
 <h3>Quina és la instrucció adequada per llegir el valor entrat per l'usuari a través del següent element HTML? <br>
 <span class="codiPrograma"><p>&lt;input type="text" id="a"&gt;</p></span>
 </h3>
 <div class="respostes">
 <input type="radio" name="pregunta4" id="p4r1">
 <label class="codi" for="p4r1">var x = document.getElementById('a').value;</label><br>
 <input type="radio" name="pregunta4" id="p4r2">
 <label class="codi" for="p4r2">var a = document.getElementById("a").value;</label><br>
 <input type="radio" name="pregunta4" id="p4r3">
 <label class="codi" for="p4r3">var a = document.getElementById("a").value();</label><br>
 <input type="radio" name="pregunta4" id="p4r4">
 <label for="p4r4">No es pot llegir perquè falta l'atribut size en l'element HTML</label><br>
 <input type="radio" name="pregunta4" id="p4r0">
 <label for="p4r0">No contesto</label><br>
 </div>
</fieldset>
<fieldset class="pregunta">
<legend>Pregunta 5</legend>
 <h3>Quin és el resultat d'executar la següent funció? <br>
   <span class="codiPrograma"><p>function pregunta5(){</br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;const A=5, B=10;</br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;return B%2 - A*B/2;<br>}</p></span>
 </h3>
 <div class="respostes">
 <input type="radio" name="pregunta5" id="p5r1">
 <label class="codi" for="p5r1">25</label><br>
 <input type="radio" name="pregunta5" id="p5r2">
 <label class="codi" for="p5r2">-20</label><br>
 <input type="radio" name="pregunta5" id="p5r3">
 <label for="p5r3">No es pot executar perquè té errors sintàctics</label><br>
 <input type="radio" name="pregunta5" id="p5r4">
 <label class="codi" for="p5r4">-25</label><br>
 <input type="radio" name="pregunta5" id="p5r0">
 <label for="p5r0">No contesto</label><br>
 </div>
</fieldset>
<fieldset class="pregunta">
<legend>Pregunta 6</legend>
 <h3>Quin és el resultat d'executar la funció programa()?<br>
   <span class="codiPrograma"><p>function programa(){<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;var x=2, y=5;<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;y=pregunta6(x,y);<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;alert("El resultat és " + x);<br>}<br>function pregunta6(x,y){<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;x=x+y;<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;return x;<br>}</p></span>
 </h3>
 <div class="respostes">
 <input type="radio" name="pregunta6" id="p6r1">
 <label class="codi" for="p6r1">El resultat és 5</label><br>
 <input type="radio" name="pregunta6" id="p6r2">
 <label class="codi" for="p6r2">El resultat és 7</label><br>
 <input type="radio" name="pregunta6" id="p6r3">
 <label class="codi" for="p6r3">El resultat és 2</label><br>
 <input type="radio" name="pregunta6" id="p6r4">
 <label class="codi" for="p6r4">El resultat és 6</label><br>
 <input type="radio" name="pregunta6" id="p6r0">
 <label for="p6r0">No contesto</label><br>
 </div>
</fieldset>
<fieldset class="pregunta">
<legend>Pregunta 7</legend>
 <h3>Quina d'aquestes funcions NO calcula correctament la suma de tots els nombres imparells que hi ha entre 5 i 186, ambdós inclosos? <br>
 <span class="codiPrograma"> <br>function funcioA() {<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;var resultat=0;<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;var i;<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;for (i=186; i>5; i--)<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;if(i%2==1) resultat=resultat+i;<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;return resultat;<br>}<br>function funcioB(){<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;var resultat=0;<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;var i;<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;for(i=5; i&lt;=186; i++)<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;if(i%2==1) resultat=resultat+i;<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;return resultat;<br>}<br>function funcioC(){<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;var resultat=0;<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;var i;<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;for(i=5; i&lt;=186; i=i+2)<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;resultat=resultat+i;<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;return resultat;<br>}<br>function funcioD(){<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;var resultat=0;<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;var i;<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;for(i=5; i&lt;=186; i++)<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;if(i%2=1) resultat=resultat+i;<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;return resultat;<br>}</span>
 </h3>
 <div class="respostes">
 <input type="radio" name="pregunta7" id="p7r1">
 <label class="codi" for="p7r1">funcioA</label><br>
 <input type="radio" name="pregunta7" id="p7r2">
 <label class="codi" for="p7r2">funcioB</label><br>
 <input type="radio" name="pregunta7" id="p7r3">
 <label class="codi" for="p7r3">funcioC</label><br>
 <input type="radio" name="pregunta7" id="p7r4">
 <label class="codi" for="p7r4">funcioD</label><br>
 <input type="radio" name="pregunta7" id="p7r0">
 <label for="p7r0">No contesto</label><br>
 </div>
</fieldset>
<fieldset class="pregunta">
<legend>Pregunta 8</legend>
 <h3>Donat l'objecte <span class="codiPrograma">var rectangle={posicio: {x:"3", y:"5"}, amplada:"10", alçada:"20"}</span> quina expressió calcula correctament l'àrea del mateix?
 </h3>
 <div class="respostes">
 <input type="radio" name="pregunta8" id="p8r1">
 <label class="codi" for="p8r1">amplada*alçada</label><br>
 <input type="radio" name="pregunta8" id="p8r2">
 <label class="codi" for="p8r2">amplada.rectangle*alçada.rectangle</label><br>
 <input type="radio" name="pregunta8" id="p8r3">
 <label class="codi" for="p8r3">rectangle.amplada*rectangle.alçada</label><br>
 <input type="radio" name="pregunta8" id="p8r4">
 <label class="codi" for="p8r4">parseInt("rectangle.amplada")*parseInt("rectangle.alçada")</label><br>
 <input type="radio" name="pregunta8" id="p8r0">
 <label for="p8r0">No contesto</label><br>
 </div>
</fieldset>
<fieldset class="pregunta">
<legend>Pregunta 9</legend>
 <h3>Amb el mateix rectangle de la pregunta anterior, quina instrucció el mouria a la nova posició<span class="codiPrograma"> x="7"</span> i <span class="codiPrograma">y="9"</span>?
 </h3>
 <div class="respostes">
 <input type="radio" name="pregunta9" id="p9r1">
 <label class="codi" for="p9r1">rectangle.posiciox="7"; rectangle.posicioy="9";</label><br>
 <input type="radio" name="pregunta9" id="p9r2">
 <label class="codi" for="p9r2">rectangle.posicio.y="9"; rectangle.posicio.x="7";</label><br>
 <input type="radio" name="pregunta9" id="p9r3">
 <label class="codi" for="p9r3">posicio.x="7"; posicio.y="9";</label><br>
 <input type="radio" name="pregunta9" id="p9r4">
 <label class="codi" for="p9r4">posicio.x="7" && posicio.y="9";</label><br>
 <input type="radio" name="pregunta9" id="p9r0">
 <label for="p9r0">No contesto</label><br>
 </div>
</fieldset>
<fieldset class="pregunta">
<legend>Pregunta 10</legend>
 <h3>Quina cadena de caràcters avalua la següent expressió? <br>
 <span class="codiPrograma">"Hola. ".charAt(2)+"Que tal?".toLowerCase()</span>
 </h3>
 <div class="respostes">
 <input type="radio" name="pregunta10" id="p10r1">
 <label class="codi" for="p10r1">"Hola. Que tal?"</label><br>
 <input type="radio" name="pregunta10" id="p10r2">
 <label class="codi" for="p10r2">"lque tal="</label><br>
 <input type="radio" name="pregunta10" id="p10r3">
 <label class="codi" for="p10r3">"oque tal??"</label><br>
 <input type="radio" name="pregunta10" id="p10r4">
 <label class="codi" for="p10r4">"hola. que tal?"</label><br>
 <input type="radio" name="pregunta10" id="p10r0">
 <label for="p10r0">No contesto</label><br>
 </div>
</fieldset>
<br>
<button id="boto" class="boto" type="button" onClick="calcul()">Calcular Nota</button>
</div>
```

Once you're comfortable with loops, there are quite a few other ways to improve this further. I encourage you to look at several of the places where nearly identical code is repeated many times and see if you can reduce it to a simpler loop.

Comment: The N/A answers do not rest 0.5. So if I create another array for the incorrect ones and add another `else if` it should work, right?

Comment: And another question, what's the effect of  `!` in `else if (!RespostesNA[i])`?

Comment: @ArnauJiménezBuxadé `!` is the [logical not](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators) operator. `if (x == true)` is roughly equivalent to `if (x)` and `if (x == false)` is roughly equivalent to `if (!x)` (there are a few cases where these are different but they're not particularly relevant here). In other words, I don't believe you need another array for incorrect answer; `if (!RespostesNA[i])` basically means `if user didn't select the n/a answer`.

Comment: Now that I know what ! means, yes. I don't need another array. That works then, thanks a lot!

Comment: Another thing I noticed is that if all the answers are blank, the mark is a -5. Why's that? Shouldn't it be 0? And how do I make it for the mark not to be able to be above 0?

Comment: @ArnauJiménez My code assumes that the user had selected some answer in every question. Of course, if you want to allow the user to leave some questions blank and calculate the score of the other answers, you will need to account for that. You could go back to the idea having an array of incorrect answers, but note again that loops can help you out quite a bit in this regard.

Comment: Thanks. Last thing, how can I add to the alert a list of the 10 questions followed with `:` and display if they are correct or incorrect?

Comment: @ArnauJiménez Read MDN [`String`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String) for information about formatting and concatenating strings, but again, take some time to think about how a loop can help you. I'd suggest constructing an array of answer results (`"correct"`, `"incorrect"`, or `"skipped"`), then you can loop through this array to compute the final score as well as format the result message.

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly recommend to use JQuery, then you could use something like this to check the users awnser

```js
var awnsers = {1,2,4,2...} //Correct awnsers
var userAwnsers = {}

$(".pregunta").each((i, elm)=>{
    $.each(elm,(i,r)=>{
        if(r.checked) 
        {
            userAwnser.push(i);
        }
    })
})
```

or in plain JS

```
var awnsers = {1,2,4,2...} //Correct awnsers
var userAwnsers = {}

var questions = document.querySelectorAll(".pregunta");

    questions.forEach((elm)=>{
        var userq = elm.querySelectorAll("[type='ratio']");
        userq.forEach((e,i)=>{
            if(e.checked) userAwnser.push(i)
        })
    });
});
```

and then lastly you could compare the awnser array with the userAwnser to check if the user gained a point

```js
var score = 0;

awnsers.forEach((e,i)=> if(e == userAwnsers[i]) score++)
```

btw if you did not know the `()=>{}` is simply a shorthand for `function(){}` and when you are writing a function inline such as the last `forEach` loop you don't have to use the brackets, that includes if statements

Comment: Our teacher hasn't explained JQuery yet, so I have to use JS. Anyway, thanks for the advice and the tips :)

Comment: I'm self thought, and i highly recommend leaning JQuery, it is not difficult to learn and will increase your efficiency + almost every webpage use it

Answer (score 0):

You need to make use of the value of these radio buttons.

```
<input type="radio" name="pregunta1" id="p1r1" value="-0.5">
<input type="radio" name="pregunta1" id="p1r2" value="1">
<!-- continue adding the correct values! -->
```

And then your function becomes as simple as,

```
function calcul(){
   var val1 = parseFloat(getRadioVal("pregunta1"));
   var val2 = parseFloat(getRadioVal("pregunta2"));
  //etc
  result = val1 + val2;  // +val3, etc
}

//UPDATE added this function to avoid querySelector
function getRadioVal(name) {
            var val;
            // get list of radio buttons with specified name
            var radios = document.getElementsByName(name);

            // loop through list of radio buttons
            for (var i=0, len=radios.length; i<len; i++) {
                if ( radios[i].checked ) { // radio checked?
                    val = radios[i].value; // if so, hold its value in val
                    break; // and break out of for loop
                }
            }
            return val; // return value of checked radio or undefined if none checked
        }
```

Comment: That's clever. Would it be possible to use js instead of query? Our teacher hasn't explained query yet.

Comment: This is js but more recent.  Better to accomplish it by the book's examples I would say.  jQuery has functions to make this even shorter.  Good luck!

Comment: I made an update utilizing getElementsByName() function.  I believe the teacher is showing how much easier it is to use Name than Id when you have a series of radio buttons grouped into pregunta1, pregunta2, etc